# AES Encryption adds junk character in Blackberry

Tags: java, encryption, blackberry, aes

I have one problem. In my application, I am using AES Encryption and Decryption. When I encrypt data and send it to the server side, it shows some junk characters added to encrypted data. But how?

Actually, this encrypted data is perfectly decrypted from my side, but there are junk characters when received by the server.

Here is my encryption code:

```
public static  byte[] encrypt( byte[] keyData, byte[] data )
throws CryptoException, IOException
{
    // Create the AES key to use for encrypting the data.
    // This will create an AES key using as much of the keyData
    // as possible.

    AESKey key = new AESKey( keyData );

    // Now, we want to encrypt the data.
    // First, create the encryptor engine that we use for the actual
    // encrypting of the data.
    AESEncryptorEngine engine = new AESEncryptorEngine( key );

    // Since we cannot guarantee that the data will be of an equal block
    // length we want to use a padding engine (PKCS5 in this case).
    PKCS5FormatterEngine fengine = new PKCS5FormatterEngine( engine );

    // Create a BlockEncryptor to hide the engine details away.
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BlockEncryptor encryptor = new BlockEncryptor( fengine, output );

    encryptor.write( data );

    encryptor.close();
    output.close();

    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Note that I don't have access to the decryption logic on the server.

Comment: Block ciphers like AES need paddings. It's absolutely normal that the encrypted data is longer than the original. You don't need to do anything at all in the client side I think.

Comment: The guys at the server side obviously have not a clue on how to handle encryption/decryption. You may want to indicate this to the right person in the organization. What they are doing is completely unsafe.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear on whether you're decrypting on the server side or if you're calling them junk characters just because there are more bytes than the original data had. If it's always 16 or less bytes added then that's the PKCS5 padding that's used to make your data divisible by the block size of the cipher. It's not visible after decryption because the decryptor automatically strips the pad.

However, looking at the Blackberry documentation I would suggest you change your encryption because BlockEncryptor defaults to ECB mode. This is a [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) that leaks information about the plaintext quite easily. Instead, choose a subclass of BlockEncryptor such as [CBCEncryptorEngine](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/CBCEncryptorEngine.html). You will need to transmit the IV along with your ciphertext for decryption later in this model.

Be very, very careful when implementing encryption using constructs like what Blackberry provides. It's very easy to make mistakes (like using ECB) and the resulting ciphertext may look fine while being fundamentally broken.

Comment: But i should use ECB mode because at server side ECB mode is used.. can you help me how to remove junk characters while encrypting data in Blackberry ?

Comment: If you have any control over server side please change it. ECB is not a secure mode. If you don't have control, the issue is likely to be that the decryption on the server side doesn't understand padding. You can strip it yourself if you look at the value of the last byte. Assuming it's PKCS5/PKCS7 padding then whatever the integer representation of that byte is tells you the number of bytes to strip. For example, 03 would mean the last 3 bytes should be stripped (and all 3 will be value 03).

Comment: encrypted data from Android and J2ME are perfectly decrypted from server side except Blackberry. so at server side we can not change logic of decryption.. so i can't understand what is problem and what should be done..?

Comment: Please edit this kind of info *in your question* as well. I drew up an answer, only to find this particular comment when I re-read Paul's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably in the decryption code of course, which you haven't shown. It is likely that you don't use a [padding mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) during decryption. Because of this, the padded characters are treated like plain text. They will probably contain byte values such as:

```
01
0202
030303
```

This is known as [PKCS#5 padding or PKCS#7 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding). It has been specified by you during encryption (`PKCS5FormatterEngine`).

These should be removed at the server's side after decryption. If possible, use a library to do this. PKCS#5 padding is always added, so it is pretty simple to remove the padding bytes yourself too.non-printable characters

---

As you have indicated in a comment on an answer, if you cannot change the server side then you should change the client side to use *zero byte padding*. This simply adds zero bytes to the plain text until it you can divide the plain text by the block size. This you probably have to do manually. It seems that the server side simply decrypts the plain text, and then it probably uses null terminated strings, or it "trims" the plain text, removing any whitespace (including terminating characters). Then encrypt, but without using the `PKCS5FormatterEngine` of course.

---

Note that PKCS#5 nor zero byte padding does not add authenticity nor integrity, and if you use ECB/CBC encryption with this kind of padding then you are likely vulnerable to [padding oracle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack). Retrieval of the plain text in 128 tries per byte of plaintext.

Comment: Let me guess, you are using PHP on the server side... it does not contain PKCS#5 padding.